# How does the "na" param work in pandas str.contains(na=x)?

Tags: python, pandas

What happens in `.contains(na=True)` or `.contains(na=False)`? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The method is called [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). The `na` param controls what happens when it encounters NaN values.

Examples:

- Given a Series `s` (first value is NaN):

  ```
  s = pd.Series([np.nan, 'foo', 'bar'])
  ```
- Normally [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) will return NaN when it encounters NaN (first value in this case):

  ```
  s.str.contains('oo')

  # 0      NaN <-
  # 1     True
  # 2    False
  ```
- If we specify `na=False` (or `na=True`), it will return `False` (or `True`) instead:

  ```
  s.str.contains('oo', na=False)

  # 0    False <-
  # 1     True
  # 2    False
  ```
- Or we can specify any arbitrary value:

  ```
  s.str.contains('oo', na='xyz')

  # 0      xyz <-
  # 1     True
  # 2    False
  ```